# How to split with chapter, section, ... Titles in the index part?

Tags: formatting, indexing, sorting

Maybe the title isn't clear.

In fact, I'm taking note during my course, and  sometimes, teachers said that a thing is a pipe (tip, stuff to know) for the examination. Since the tex have a few of them, and more then 1000 lines when finished, I'm using `\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}` to be able to have multiple index, and one only with the pipe (but there some others index with other content made the same way).

Works fine, but the problem is, I don't have the part-chapter-section-subsection-subsubsection title reference (and having paragraph and sub title reference could be nice too).

Is there a way to have it ? By adding a column, putting the entire title (chapter etc.) before the indexed sentence ?

Here, an exemple of what I'd like it look like :

[image: The better, what I'd like.]

Or, if not possible, like if titles (of the part, chapter, etc.) was add before (or after, I don't really care) the page number :

[image: If 1st not possible to do.]

I've put the page number in bold to more clear, but it's not need.

**The aim here, is to be able to know immediately, without having to look where it is with the page number (same with the number of the part/chapter/section... Since it could change very easly), where is the indexed text in the document, and so about what is talking about.**

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution uses the same method as the table of contents is generated.
The entries for the list of important things are written to the `.aux` file, then at the end of the document LaTeX writes it to the file `\jobname.imp`. In the next run this file is read and a table is set.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newlength\ImpLineWidth
\newtoks\ImpToks
\newcommand*{\printimportant}{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{\centering Index of important things}%
  \setlength{\ImpLineWidth}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\ImpLineWidth}{-2\tabcolsep}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}p{.6\ImpLineWidth}p{.4\ImpLineWidth}@{}}%
  \global\ImpToks{}%
  \@starttoc{imp}%  
  \the\ImpToks
  \end{longtable}%
}
\newcommand*{\importantentry}[2]{%
  \global\ImpToks\expandafter{%   
    \the\ImpToks
    \centering #1&
    \centering #2\tabularnewline
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand*{\important}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{imp}{%
    \protect\importantentry{#1}{%
      \ifnum\value{part}=0 %
      \else
        part~\thepart, %
      \fi
      \ifnum\value{chapter}=0 %
      \else
        chapter~\thechapter, %
        \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
        \else
          section~\thesection, %
        \fi
      \fi  
      page~\thepage
    }%
  }%  
}     
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{First part}
\important{Some indexed \dots}
\chapter{First chapter}
\important{Again}
\section{First section}
\important{Idem 1}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\important{Idem 2}
\printimportant   
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

### Index based variant

The following uses the index machinery. For the case that there is already an index I have used package `index` to get a second one. (There are other packages like `multind`, …)

The sectioning titles are usually not available. Exception is the latest title that packages like `titleref`, `nameref` or `zref-titleref` remember. For the best control of the numbering and title, the sectioning commands needs to be patched. Here I have used a shortcut via `\addcontentsline` assuming that only sectioning titles are relevant that also goes into the table of contents. A glitch remains, the large space between the part number and the part title, the standardclass uses the hardcoded `\hspace{1em}` here.
But anyway, you are using a different unknown setup as the word numbering shows.
For simplicity it is also assumed that the part title is always present.

The first LaTeX run of `test.tex` generates `test.imx`. The final index file `test.imp` is generated via:

```
makeindex -o test.imp test.imx
```

Also a different style file than the standard settings can be used to control the output of the final index file.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{index}
\newindex{imp}{imx}{imp}{Index of important things}

\makeatletter
\newlength\ImpLineWidth
\newtoks\ImpToks
\newcommand*{\printimportant}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\numberline##1{##1:~}%
    \renewcommand*{\theindex}{%
      \clearpage
      \section*{\centering Index of important things}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus .5ex minus .25ex}%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
      \let\item\@idxitem
    }{%
      \clearpage
    }%
    \printindex[imp]%
  \endgroup
}

% Remember sectioning titles
\newcommand*{\imp@toc}{toc}
\@ifdefinable{\imp@org@addcontentsline}{%
  \let\imp@org@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
  \renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \edef\imp@temp{#1}%
    \ifx\imp@temp\imp@toc
      \begingroup
        \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname imp@current@#2\endcsname{#3}%
        \csname imp@cleanup@#2\endcsname
      \endgroup
    \fi
    \imp@org@addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
% Clear subordinate sectioning titles
\def\imp@temp#1#2{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname imp@cleanup@#1\endcsname{%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname imp@current@#2\endcsname\@empty
    \csname imp@cleanup@#2\endcsname
  }%
}
\imp@temp{part}{chapter}
\imp@temp{chapter}{section}
\imp@temp{section}{subsection}

\newcommand*{\important}[2][]{%
  \def\imp@temp{#1}%
  \protected@edef\imp@temp{%
    \noexpand\index[imp]{%  
      \ifx\imp@temp\@empty 
      \else
        #1@%
      \fi
      #2; %
      % assuming the part is always present.
      part~\csname imp@current@part\endcsname
      \ifx\imp@current@chapter\@empty
      \else
        , chapter~\csname imp@current@chapter\endcsname
        % section, ...
      \fi
      |textbf%
    }%
  }%
  \imp@temp
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\important{Some indexed \dots}
\chapter{First chapter}
\important{Again}
\section{First section}
\important{Idem 1}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\important{Idem 2}
\printimportant
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Impressive, but not exactly my goal. Here, you're doing your own kind of index. Clearly, I could use it. However, it seems to only put the number of the part/chapter, etc. And not the name, which is the most important for me. And, it doesn't use index, so the data aren't sort. Finally, I've forgot to mention it, but I would prefer the 1st solution rather than the 2nd. What you did, so quickly is great, but maybe for a in case of solution (because pretty time-eater to put in place). Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first example the sorting order is document order, the second example does not specify any order. Also the examples do not show any chapter/section/... titles. Therefore the question should be refined.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. I've realized it a bit after reading your solution. Is it more clear now ? By the way, your solution is quite cool, for both the result, but also the means.

Comment: Sorry, it's not too clear for me. The second example is too short and without explicit page numbers to show the data sorting. And do you really want to sort the entries inside part/chapter, but keeping document order for parts/chapters?

Comment: Impressive ! But, 5 questions remains : what does ~ do ? Why are you using `\section*{\centering Index of important things}%` line ? Since "Index of important things" is your one of you're index title, you shouldn't have to do it, no ? Why the text is only in the index ? Why make a new command in stead of using the `\printindex` one ? And, would it work with `\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}` ? Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to try and adopt the code to your needs. Of course you can use `\printindex[imp]` with two column layout or whatever you like.

Comment: Ok, no problems. To remake it for one or two other index, should I remake it completly for all or is there a shortest way ? And, just to be sure, it's not possible to have part/chapter... Title print upside the indexed text like in the solution one ?